# backup only some files using vbs

Tags: vbscript, backup, xlsx

I want to make an automatic backup of my excel files using vbscript.
It works to copy the entire folder but I want to copy only the xlsx files.
Here is the code until now:

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, evrFiles
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set evrFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each evrFile in evrFiles
    If InStr(1, evrFile.Name, ".xlsx", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\vbs\" & evrFile.Name, "E:\test2"
    End If

Next

WScript.Quit
```

It throws error on line 5 char 1 "Object required: " "

Any ideas?

LE: I have also tried:

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder
Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strUser = wshNetwork.Username
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs")
Set evrFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each evrFile in evrFiles
    If InStr(1, evrFile.Name, ".xlsx", vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
        objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs\" & evrFile.Name, "E:\test2"
    End If
Next
WScript.Quit
```

But this one gives me "Permission denied on line 9 char 3"

This one works(to copy the entire folder) but I want only the excel files.

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strUser = wshNetwork.Username


objFSO.CopyFolder"C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs","E:\test2"
```

Comment: So do you have permissions for the folders C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs\ and E:\test2 ?  And try with the destination as "E:\test2\"

Comment: @lostbard yes because if I try to copy the entire folder it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to iterrate each file, you could do something like:

```
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strUser = wshNetwork.Username

objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs\*.xlsx", "E:\test2\"
```

You may also want to set the overwrite flag when doing the copy, it there will be existing files already in the destination folder.

```
objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs\*.xlsx","E:\test2", True
```

Comment: objFSO.CopyFolder "C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs\*.xlxs", "E:\test2\" it say path not found.

Comment: you missed the \ before the wildcard - and i had a typo - use the correct file extension

Comment: objFSO.CopyFolder"C:\Users\" & strUser & "\Desktop\vbs\*.xlsx","E:\test2", True still path not found (windows 8.1 pro)

Comment: see edits above